# Clear or Disable Cache in ArcObjects Globe Control

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, 3d-analyst, cache, arcglobe

Is it possible to clear or disable the cache for individual layers on the AxGlobeControl? If so, how? I would like to be able to do this programatically through ArcObjects.

Comment: Is this a question that you are still hoping for an Answer on?  If so, could you update its version tag to whatever you are currently using?  If you now know the answer it would be great if you could add that and then self-Accept it.